# Increase visibility of full screen view with animation

Tags: android, translation, visibility

I am writing an view where I need to display another full screen overlay view from bottom to top.

View State:

- Initially state of overlay view is hide,
- Then 10% of view will visible
- Then 20 % and so on up to 100%.

So it's only visibility of view not to push view from bottom to top. I am using following for same:

```
<translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="75%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

but it push view instead to display.

**EDIT** Added layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fmParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGameLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/fake_percentage"
        android:textColor="@color/theme_blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_header_size" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/txt_bottom_margin"
        android:text="@string/connecting"
        android:textColor="@color/theme_blue" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fmOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/theme_blue"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fake_percentage"
            android:textColor="@color/theme_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_header_size" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Solved: Vikarm solution work great for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/25436139/2624806 :)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say that I fully understand what your are looking for. Do you want to reveal 'main content' from bottom-to-top? Like this?

[image]

If this is what you have in mind, use an `ObjectAnimator` to animate `bottom` property of the `overlay` layout container. You can leave a comment if you need more help.

**Edit:**

Whenever you want to animate-reveal, call this method:

```
public void animateReveal() {
    // We need this value to reset framelayout's bottom value once 
    // the animation is done running - in case we need to run the 
    // animation again
    final int originalBottomValue = fmOverlay.getBottom();

    // Animator - animated the bottom property of the FrameLayout
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(fmOverlay, "bottom", 
                                               fmOverlay.getBottom(), 0);

    // Duration is currently set to 3000ms - 3 seconds
    anim.setDuration(3000L);

    // Add a listener to the animation
    anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

            // Set framelayout to be invisible
            fmOverlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // Restore the `bottom` value
            fmOverlay.setBottom(originalBottomValue);
        }
    });

    // Start animation
    anim.start();
}
```

Comment: @Shubh Can you post your layout? It will easier to explain then. :)

Comment: @Shubh Thanks. I have added an `Edit` to my answer. Please check and report if it works fine for you.

Comment: Thanks Vikram,...it's working in direction I wanted...I need some more help here..overlay view should not be visible completely, it should visible in order(increasing level)...also is it possible to pause animation for sometime and then resume.

Comment: Thanks Vikram...here I stuck on an logical issue. Base and overlay layout both have text to show percentage. So overlay text override by base layout..any suggestion to highlight overlay textview when it level animation passing it.

Comment: @Shubh I can help you tomorrow. I'll leave the contact details here in a comment.

Comment: Hi Vikram ...r u available!

Comment: @Shubh Sorry about the delay. Let's talk here: [Link](http://www.twiddla.com/1748974).

Comment: Hi @Vikram  ..i need but help on it...could u please available for same.

Comment: How could this be done in the opposite direction (top to down)? I tried replacing the `bottom` with `top` and the 0 to `fm.getTop()` but it just waits for the duration and then shows the under view.

Comment: @Bootstrapper Yea, that sounds a bit tricky. I'll have to code it up. Since a month has passed (I hadn't logged in), have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alpha` tag in XML file like

```
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
   android:toAlpha="1.0"  
   android:duration="1500"/>
```

or in your Java file you can use

```
AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0,1);
alphaAnimation.setDuration(1500);
view.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
```

where `view` is the `View` which you want to make visible.

Make sure you are using the `View` that you want to make visible is above the other `View`

Comment: Thanks, but here alpha increasing in complete screen, is there any way to oncrease from bottom to top !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago.

I will explain my solution - hoping you can manipulate it to your needs.

It is all about manipulating other views on top of yours. Over my main View, I created two white-filled `Rectangles` covering the whole view. One Rec was alpha=1 at the bottom and 0 at the top (a gradient). The second Rec was the opposite - alpha=1 at the top to 0% at the bottom.

You can create the Gradient effects like so:

Create file: res/drawable/gradient_shape1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Create file: res/drawable/gradient_shape2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Now, you have 3 layers - layer 1 is your view, layer 2 is one Rec, layer 3 is the second Rec.
So when both Recs are shown at full alpha - you can see a full white rec over your view (seeing they overlap).

So, what I did now, using `AlphaAnimation` and `postDelayed` - I set the Alpha of the first Rec down to 0 (for example, duration was 2000ms), and after that duration (set by `postDelayed`) I started to fade the second Rec down to 0 alpha.

I did not achive the exact effect you are looking for but I got a nice effect that pleased me. I'm sure if you play around more with the gradients and timers you might get what you want.

Comment: Thanks..yes..but this is not what I exactly needed...in my case there should be no alpha effect..it just need to be visible slowly but not to be pushed(mention in Q.)...can u give me suggestion here!

Comment: Ohhh... I thought you meant 10-20% opacity... you need full opacity all the time but just the percentage of the visible view changes?

Comment: Try this:
Put the view in a layout if it's not and set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` for that layout. Then, just set the view to go programmatically from invisible to visible.
Let me know!

Comment: Hi gilonm...i tried with it..but it is nothing about to show view in way I want..might I am missing something..can u share example some similar to my Quesiton. I tried it but it just get visible but I need visible motion when it get visible.

Comment: Well, I do understand what you are looking for.. I have searched for a while and tried myself, unfortunately with no luck.

Hope someone out there could help you more than me.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for ur effort..let here know if you found something related.